# Помогите написать функцию на Python для парсера

Tags: python, парсер

Тренируюсь в написании парсера на Python. Есть список url. Хочу разобраться, как написать функцию, которая будет

1. Последовательно предавать один из url в переменную
2. С помощью `requests`  передавать в `soup`
3. Собирает, картинки, заголовки и контент
4. Записывать все в `file.svc`

Процесс понимаю, а вот знаний методов работы нет. Кому не трудно сделайте болванку, чтобы я разобрался и почитал, что нужно.

Comment: 1) for url in urls :

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

list_url = ['https://mail.ru', 'https://vk.com', 'https://rambler.ru']

# Перебор ссылок из списка
for url in list_url:
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(url, response)

# Получить все заголовки H[1-6]
for url in list_url:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="html.parser")
    headers = soup.find_all(re.compile('^h[1-6]$'))
    print(headers)


# Ссылки на картинки
for url in list_url:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="html.parser")
    images = []
    for img in soup.findAll('img'):
        images.append(img.get('src'))

    print(images)
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Буду ковырять.

Comment: вы можете проголосовать За ответ, если он является полезным